# How to send task to celery using redis pubsub with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, python, redis

How do you send task to celery through redis pubsub once a new record has been inserted into a postgresql table?

My problem here is to get redis to listen for inserts in my postgresql table, and when it detects an insert, it should send tasks to celery. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell redis that you have inserted a record in your table, not the other way around.

Comment: Whenever you do an insert to your database, you have to publish the fact on a redis channel. If redis is listening to the same channel this will solve your problem